# When discussing age in Greek, is use of the aorist tense more indicative of when one turned a certain age rather than them just simply being that age?

Tags: greek

**The Greek text for Luke 2:42 reads:**
Καὶ ὅτε ἐγένετο ἐτῶν δώδεκα, ἀναβαινόντων αὐτῶν κατὰ τὸ ἔθος τῆς ἑορτῆς

**The English translation (KJV) of Luke 2:42 reads:**
And when he was twelve years old, they went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast

Here "was" is a translation of the Greek word "ἐγένετο." In the Greek, "ἐγένετο" is in the aorist tense. Is it true that when discussing age, the use of the aorist tense for "was" suggests the time when someone *turned*/*became* a certain age? Furthermore, is it true that if looking to communicate one simply being a certain age (rather than the actual point in time when they turned that age), a verb in the imperfect tense would be used for "was?" Thanks for the help!

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://latin.stackexchange.com/ : that site includes classical Greek as well as Latin